# How can I run a second site in Azure while sharing the domain?

Tags: web-server, subdomain, azure, asp.net-mvc

I have a site running on Azure built in ASP.NET MVC.  Part of the site is effectively a marketing site with mostly static pages, the rest is the dashboard that our users log into to use the product.

Currently it's all ASP.NET MVC tucked away in a Visual Studio solution, and effectively unreachable by anyone without access to the code.  I'd like to expose the marketing pages so they can be edited without access to the code, also allowing them to be changed without compiling the solution and publishing it.

So, I'd like to figure out how to split our site into two, one that continues to run the dashboard site (could be http://app.domain.com) and another that's driven by Wordpress (http://domain.com) for all of the "about us" and marketing chatter.  Currently we have 1 web site in Azure.  How can I run a second site in Azure while sharing the domain?  Any thoughts on a cost effective way to approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just done something similar to what you're asking about, using Azure Websites - 
I have a public facing website, call it Yossi.co.uk (not real) and I have an API I wanted published on the same domain. the web site and the api each have their own Azure Website (Yossi.azurewebsites.net and yossiapi.azurewebsites.net respectively)

I manage my domain with 123-reg so in their advanced DNS settings I've added the awverify records

I have the following three records for the public website - one CNAME to drive internet traffic and two to support verification of both naked domain and full domain

```
awverify CNAME awverify.yossi.azurewebsites.net.
awverify.www CNAME awverify.yossi.azurewebsites.net
www CNAME yossi.azurewebsites.net.
```

I then added the following for the API - again - one for the verification and one for actual traffic

```
awverify.api CNAME awverify.yossiapi.azurewebsites.net
api CNAME yossiapi.azurewebsites.net
```

As you can see in my DNS records I simply needed to add another set for the subdomain - one for verification and one for traffic and I got two separate websites as part of the same domain.

I then went to both Azure websites on the Azure Management Portal, made sure they are both Shared or Standard instances, to ensure support for custom domains and then in the configure tab I added the custom domains. (without the correct verification records this would fail, but will show which verification entries in the DNS need adding)

Worth noting that DNS takes a while to update, so you will need to wait a little bit between updating the DNS records and successfully updating the custom domain in Azure.

Comment: With pleasure, glad I could help